# running multiple files on node js at the same time

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have a simple node script

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337);
```

now when i run this, i can go to localhost:1337 and see the output but , in the command module, its frozen for some reason. until i press ctrl+C its frozen and only after Ctrl+C im allowed to execute more files.

is this just me or its the way it was designed. If it is can someone point me in the right direction as to how to have it always listen on port 1337 or another for different files.

Comment: which version of node are you running? I copy pasted yours into mine (0.10.9) and was fine (could get an http response on 1337, but could still type into the prompt)

Comment: im running 0.10.15 .... mine gets stuck until ctrl+c

Comment: from their website its http://nodejs.org/download/ 0.10.15 which is the current version , on and btw its on windows 8 with node js command prompt.

Comment: Why not just run another terminal?

Comment: @user1690718, It's not getting stuck, it's waiting for more connections.  You created an HTTP server which is listening for connections.  Until you stop that server, your code won't exit.

Comment: @Brad ah, you got it I think.  I interpreted their question as "not able to enter more code into nodejs", but incorrectly so

Comment: so how to i run more files ? open more nodes ?

Comment: @user1690718, It isn't clear what you mean by "run more files".  If you want to run several processes at the same time, open several terminals and do that.  You can also use `forever` easily run and control the process in the background.

Answer (score 2):

This is normal behavior.  Node will only exit if there's nothing more to do (or if you manually stop it via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).  Since you told http to `listen()`, the process will stay alive indefinitely.

It's not exactly clear what you're asking, but if you want to run additional files inside your app, you simply `require()` them.

```
var otherFile = require('./otherFile.js') // the .js is optional
```

`otherFile` will now be set to whatever you do to `module.exports` in otherFile.js.

You should [read the module documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) to get a full understanding of how `require` works.

If you want to run other unrelated files with node at the same time, open a separate command prompt window.

---

I will now read between the lines a little: it looks like you might be wondering how to get http to serve files from disk like other web servers.  Node doesn't work like traditional web servers.  Your code has to explicitly handle serving up things from disk.

Fortunately, there are frameworks/libraries that make it easy to do.  If you're building any kind of web service, you should really use a framework rather than the raw http module.  I recommend looking at [Express](http://expressjs.com/).  It's easy to serve files from disk with [`express.static`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use).